# loadUrl in OAuth-wso2is and flow oauth

Tags: android, url, webview, oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to develop an app in Android using WSO2's and OAuth. When I create WebView in MainActivity I wrote the lollowing Code:

> auth_dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
>                       auth_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.auth_dialog);
>                       web = (WebView) auth_dialog.findViewById(R.id.webview); 
>                       web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>                       web.loadUrl("https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_URI);

I think the error is in the url that step as a parameter to loadURL (). how do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the URL host name is wrong. It should have the hostname of the server where IS is hosted. If you are running this on android, `localhost` would refer to the device itself, not the server IS is hosted.

If you are running this in an emulator, you should use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost` to refer the development machine.

Comment: WSO2IS It is installed on a virtual machine a while the server (Tomcat) and Su Another virtual machine again. The client application The settle in Tomcat / webapp and I feel the execution of an emulator, right? But the Address What can I insert now what? I have a great confusion in the head. Can you explain?